# autoLayout not fitting all my screen sizes

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, constraints

this is basic problem but when I come across to complex views issues pops up when in intermediate level.

I show you two shot of my main page of App first one is my favorite (what I want) second needs more work to be.

[image]

look carefully UIimageS are closer to each other and bigger and enough space from two bottom button (running on s5)

[image]

but this one are far from each other and smaller and far from two bottom button and Unuseful space area (running on s6 plus)

my question and problem is if swift compiler decides when to increase icon sizes why not increasing now ??

could any body constraint this view and show me the result? what is my mistake ?? what am I missing ?

what I'm doing is giving width and hight and center alignment and vertical spacing for one of icon on top right.

you tell me how to constraint for all screen as my favorite
my view is not messed up but what is bugging me is extra spaces

android is doing better it has a screen size file can manipullate it for all sizes

Comment: The simplest solution is to use `UICollectionView`.

Comment: any other solution. ?

Comment: You can also try with stackview

Comment: both uicollectionView and stackView would work but my question is what is stackView doing that I can't do with out it ? I'm trying to do it with constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this pretty easily using nested `UIStackView`s, as follows…

**8 Plus size phone…**

[image]

**4S size phone…**

[image]

Comment: both uicollectionView and stackView would work but my question is what is stackView doing that I can't do with out it ? I'm trying to do it with constraints

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't use `UIStackView`? Or are you just trying to understand how to build the constraints from scratch? There's probably more than one issue with your constraints - for a start you don't seem to be adjusting the image sizes. You'll need to set width/height constraints between each image and the main view, with a multiplier, that depends on insets, inter-image spacing, label size, number of images in a row / column, etc. Or just use a `UIStackView`